# Исключение в Android

Tags: java, android, eclipse, исключения

Доброго времени суток! Помогите пожалуйста с такой проблемой. Есть приложение Android. Запускаю главную активити, затем жму системную кнопку назад и сразу же получаю какая-то непонятная ошибка. Вот скриншот из эклипса:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Само исключение отловить не могу потому что даже не знаю где оно происходит, к тому же как я писал выше происходит эта ошибка при нажатии на системную кнопку "назад". Я это нажатие нигде не обрабатываю. 
Я добавил обработчик всех необработанных исключений примерно так

```
Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler (new Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler()
 {
    @Override
    public void uncaughtException (Thread thread, Throwable e) {
        // тут код обработки исключения
    }
});
```

но проблема в том что когда прроисходит эта ошибка, этот обработчик даже не вызывается. В LogCat тоже ничего интересного почему-то нету((

Хотелось бы узнать как отловить эту ошибку?

Comment: нет тут никакой ошибки. Eclipse не нашел исходный код библиотеки, внутри которой стоит breakpoint

Comment: В режиме Debug в Eclipse иногда происходят странные вещи :) Запустите без отладчика и посмотрите LogCat еще раз. Если ничего нет, значит ничего нет :)